# Translate python conditional to javascript -- control flow

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, list

How can I do this in JavaScript?  It should print 'Found' when it hits `words` in `big_list`

```
big_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'long', 'list', 'of' 'words']

needle = ['words', 'to', 'find']

for i in big_list:
    if i in needle:
        print('Found')
    else:
        print('Not Found')
```

I know the general if/else structure but am unsure the syntax:

```
if (big_list in needle) {
  console.log('print some stuff')
} else {
  console.log('print some other stuff')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function with a `for` loop like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < big_list.length; i++)
{
    if (needle.includes(big_list[i])) console.log("Found");
    else console.log("Not found");
}
```

Or using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
big_list.forEach(function(e) { 
     if (needle.includes(e)) console.log("Found");
     else console.log("Not found");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it already, but there are a few things of note. First, the `in` keyword works differently in javascript than it does in python. In python, it can be used to check if an item is a member of a collection, but in javascript, it checks if the item is a *key* of an object. So:

```
"foo" in {foo: "bar"} // True
```

but

```
"foo" in ["foo", "bar"] // False
```

Because in the second case, while `"foo"` is a member of the array, the `in` keyword is looking for it as a key. On those lines:

```
"0" in ["foo", "bar"] // True
```

Since `"0"` is a key of the array (namely the key pointing to the first item)

Other than that, your code can be adapted to javascript without changing much. Just declare your variables using `var`, `const`, or `let`, use braces with your `if`'s and replace the calls with their javascript equivalents:

```js
/*

# Python Code:
big_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'long', 'list', 'of', 'words']

needle = ['words', 'to', 'find']

for i in big_list:
    if i in needle:
        print('Found')
    else:
        print('Not Found')

*/

// Now in javascript:

const big_list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'long', 'list', 'of', 'words']
const needle = ['words', 'to', 'find']

for (let i of big_list) {
  if (needle.includes(i)) {
    console.log('Found')
  } else {
    console.log('Not Found')
  }
}
```